# C# Listenin 5060 Port

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listening to Port 5060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507166/listening-to-port-5060)

I am developing a SIP client.And I have a question.
I want listen 5060 port for catch the SIP Server Message.For this,I coding something.(Also I take admin rights in program)

But I get SocketException: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" (Native error code: 10013)...

My Code:

```
 private void ListenPort() {
        WindowsPrincipal pricipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
        bool hasAdministrativeRight = pricipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        TcpListener server = null;
        Int32 port = 5060;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.33");
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1000];
        String data = null;
    while (hasAdministrativeRight == true)
    {
        server.Start();
        int i = 0;
        while (1==1)
        {
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            data = null;
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            data += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
            label3.Text += data;
            this.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(500);

        }
    }
}
```

Where do you think the problem?

Comment: Have you tried run application as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that no other program is already using port 5060? That's what this error can mean.

See this discussion on the matter: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/d23d471c-002a-4958-829e-eb221c8a4b76/

Comment: Yes,I checked other programs,firewalls and anti-virus programs repeatedly.Everything is okay.But I don't listen this port.Very interesting

Comment: @MehmetEnder:Have you read completely the discussion liked by @Spencer Ruport? the Alan McFarlane answer seems the solution for you problem. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx Read about `WSAEACCES(10033)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call server.Start() **outside** the while loop and before the first AcceptTcpClient call. 
Also try using IPAddress.Any instead of IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.33") for your listener ip

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any other **SIP Server** program not installed as a Windows service which has using according port.

Type in `netstat -an` and it will show you the “listening” ports or try to googling port check softwares.

And check your SIP Server configuration for is it running over TCP or UDP.